# click event in jQuery not working as i expect

Tags: jquery, events, click, fadeout

i have a div and an anchor link in my page, and i referenced to jQuery correctly.
it's something like this :

```
<div id="tools"></div> <!---- which has width and height , .. --->
<a class="navtab" href="#" id="onoff">Forum Tools</a>
```

after that i put this code :

```
<script>
$("#onoff").click(function {
   $("#tools").fadeOut(2000);
});
</script>
```

i expect the div to fadeOut after 2 seconds when i click on the link. but nothing happens..
but when i use it as a simple statement without any event, it works perfectly :

```
<script>
$("#tools").fadeOut(2000);
</script>
```

to make sure that nothing's wrong i put the whole code into .load event :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#onoff").click(function {
   $("#tools").fadeOut(2000);
});
});
</script>
```

but still no chance :|

what's wrong with my code ?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that's your whole code? Because as I understand it, without the `$(document).ready(function(){ /* code goes in here */});` your code is running as it's encountered, before the DOM is ready and before any elements are present to bind events to. Also, in your first code block you've missed out the parentheses `()` that should be after your function and before the opening curly-brace `{`.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Do you have more than one element with the ID `onoff` on the page? It's the most likely cause I can think of.

Comment: @DavidThomas He said that the `<script>` tag is after the HTML for the elements, so they'll exist when the code is executed.

Comment: @Anthony: ah, yes. I...should probably stop drinking before coming onto Stackoverflow, eh? =/

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks david. you're right, it was a little mistake and with paratheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing parentheses after `function`.

```
$("#onoff").click(function {
```

should be

```
$("#onoff").click(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a () after your click(function

```
$("#onoff").click(function{
```

to

```
$("#onoff").click(function(){
```

Also, browser support might have issues if you don't use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Always make sure that you have the jQuery file included before you call any jQuery functionality:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/my/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#onoff").click(function(){
      $("#tools").fadeOut(2000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Fully functional example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/TaW6Z/